# Enabling TLS in Elasticsearch

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch

I'm having problems enabling TLS in Elasticsearch 7.1.1 running on Windows 7.

I have a single node with certificates created as

```
elasticsearch-certutil ca
elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
```

The elasticsearch.yml file has the following settings

```
node.name: node1
discovery.type:  single-node
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: 'C:\elasticsearch-7.1.1\config\certs\elastic-certificates.p12'
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: 'C:\elasticsearch-7.1.1\config\certs\elastic-certificates.p12'
```

This works fine but when I add the below

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: 'C:\elasticsearch-7.1.1\config\certs\elastic-certificates.p12'
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: 'C:\elasticsearch-7.1.1\config\certs\elastic-certificates.p12'
```

and start up elasticsearch I see the following error

> [2019-06-25T07:34:19,659][WARN ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport]
>   [node1] caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing
>   connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9200,
>   remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:6757}
>   io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record:

This is repeated every 10-15 seconds.

https is enabled though and I can access the node using `https://localhost:9200`

I don't know why I receive the above error though as nothing else is running and accessing elasticsearch.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointed out to me, on the elastic forum, that the above is a warning and not an error. I still couldn't understand what was causing it as I wasn't running any service or anything else that could be causing it but eventually found something called heartbeat that was running. This was obviously setup in an earlier version/previous installation of Kibana and this was still running, making a call using http and thus causing the above error (this is used for creating dummy data to use for/by to demo Kibana).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too. And IF you have previously installed Elastic Search then high chance you got some residual indices with "red" status, which makes the process of enabling TLS unsuccessful.
Try this command to verify your indices and their statuses

`curl -XGET https://localhost:9200/_cat/indices`

then delete those with red status.