# How to enable TLS in Elasticsearch non-interactively?

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, ssl-certificate

According to [TLS configuration docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/configuring-tls.html), to generate certificates for TLS for Elasticsearch 7.1, you run:

```
elasticsearch-certutil ca
elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
```

<sup>Related: [Enabling TLS in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56744283/55075)</sup>

The certificates are required to enable TLS via REST API.

However, the above commands require human interaction (hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

How to generate above certificates non-interactively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the commands which worked for me:

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
sudo mkdir -v certs
sudo ./bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --out certs/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass ""
sudo ./bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca certs/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass "" --out certs/elastic-certificates.p12 --pass ""
```

And the Ansible's playbook:

```
---
- name: Create a certificate directory
  file:
    owner: root
    group: '{{ elasticsearch_user_group }}'
    mode: u=rwx,g+rx,o-rwx
    path: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'
    state: directory
  when: elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir is defined
- name: Check a certificate of authority
  stat:
    path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-stack-ca.p12"
  register: elastic_stack_ca_file
- name: Generate a certificate of authority
  args:
    chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
  become: yes
  command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}'"
  when: not elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists
- name: Check a certificate and private key for a node
  stat:
    path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-certificates.p12"
  register: elastic_certificates_file
- name: Generate a certificate and private key for a node
  args:
    chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
  become: yes
  command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}' --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-certificates.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass }}'"
  when: elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists and not elastic_certificates_file.stat.exists
```

where default variables can be defined as:

```
elasticsearch_http_port: 9200
elasticsearch_path_home: "/usr/share/elasticsearch"
elasticsearch_path_etc: "/etc/elasticsearch"
elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass: ""
elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass: ""
elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir: "certs"
elasticsearch_user: "elasticsearch"
elasticsearch_user_group: "elasticsearch"
```

Further instructions:

- [A step-by-step guide to enabling security, TLS/SSL, and PKI authentication in Elasticsearch](https://alexmarquardt.com/2018/11/05/security-tls-ssl-pki-authentication-in-elasticsearch/)
- [Elasticsearch Security: Configure TLS/SSL & PKI Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-security-configure-tls-ssl-pki-authentication)
- [Encrypting communications in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/configuring-tls.html)

Comment: In ansible tasks, there is two problem when I tried seperate in the command to the argv:
1. hypen is not passed, so I escaped them like '\-\-out {{ elasticsearch_ca_path }}'
2. It stuck in long time

But in a single line in `command` as you wrote, it's ok. The problem is about ansible itself or yaml?